# How can I load large Camera RAW files (NEF) faster in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background

I have written a simple application that scrolls through a folder and displays the photos in that folder and the user can review the file and choose several actions to take with the Photo before clicking to the next one. The application works fine and when using even large Jpegs (15-19 MB) it scrolls through very quickly. ( No lag between images) however when it comes to the RAW files (20 - 25 MB) it takes 3-4 seconds for the next image to load after the user clicks next.

I have tried several options so far like setting the BitmapImage.bi.DecodePixelHeight = 1080(works fantastic for JPegs but alters the colours etc of the raw file so unusable)
I have tried using a background worker to load the next file in the queue into memory, this works quite well if you  the user spends enough time reviewing the current image but if you quickly scroll through the images you get  an error "BackgroundWorker is currently busy".
I know it can be done because the  windows 10 App "Photos" can rapidly scroll through the NEF files and I would just like some advice on how i should go about accomplishing the same speed as this.

Is there a better way to load the images in the background, is there a way I can compress the raw files to display them at 1920 * 1080 before loading them  ( currently they are 6000 * 4000) or any other ideas would be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can try to do is extract embedded jpeg image from that raw file. Most (maybe even all) cameras include full-size jpeg inside that RAW, which should be fine for your preview. I used [dcraw](http://www.centrostudiprogressofotografico.it/en/dcraw/) tool for this ([here](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) are docs). To call it from your .NET code, just call it via `Process.Start`:

```
private void ExtractJpegFromRaw(string raw, string outputPath) {
    if (!File.Exists(raw)) return;
    var dcraw = Path.Combine("path to dcraw.exe here");
    var command = String.Format("\"{0}\" -e -c -t 0 \"{1}\" > \"{2}\"", dcraw, raw, outputPath);
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", String.Format("/c \"{0}\"", command));
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();    
}
```

I must say I didn't measure perfomance of this, but extracting already existing jpeg should be fast. So what you can do is run this code then show resulting jpeg, plus you might cache that preview and next time user will view the same raw - you will have jpeg already prepared (this is what most photo viewer tools do - they cache previews).

Comment: You absolute legend, that works amazingly well thanks a million.

Comment: Good to know! Out of interest - how much speedup did you get from this?

Comment: immeasurable improvement, It went from about 3-4 seconds to load the next image to virtually instantaneous. My mere mortal eyes cant really detect the delay (if any)

Comment: By the way, I tried to upvote your answer but it appears I dont have enough reputation points to do so

Comment: Yeah you need at least 15 reputation to do that.

Comment: The `-t 0` parameter is not required.